# EmguCV "The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception"

Tags: c#, opencv, exception, emgucv

I have got a problem when using EmguCV. Everytime I try to create SIFT or SURF detector I get exception "The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception".
I've already: installed MSVCRT, copied OpenCV and Emgu dlls to the execution directory, added to solution OpenCV and Emgu dlls, added to solution Emgu.CV, Emgu.CV.GPU, Emgu.CV.ML, Emgu.CV.UI, Emgu.Util references.
Unfortunately I still got exception. I've tried to build SURFFeature example and it worked perfectly. It actually means that I make some mistake, but I can't find it... Please help...

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Features2D;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using Emgu.CV.Util;
using Emgu.CV.GPU;

namespace blablabla
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Bitmap waveform_to_file = new Bitmap(2, 2);

                //Emgu.CV.Features2D.SIFTDetector detector = new Emgu.CV.Features2D.SIFTDetector();//(0, 3, 0.04, 10, 1.6);//(400, true, 3, 4);//
                SURFDetector surfCPU = new SURFDetector(500, false);//I got exception on these lines

                Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfKeyPoint keypoints = new Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfKeyPoint();

                Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray, Byte> waveform_to_file_gray = new Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray, byte>(waveform_to_file);

                Emgu.CV.Features2D.ImageFeature<float>[] modKeyPointsArray = surfCPU/*detector*/.DetectFeatures(waveform_to_file_gray, null);

                List<Emgu.CV.Features2D.ImageFeature<float>> modKeyPointsList = new List<Emgu.CV.Features2D.ImageFeature<float>>();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Solution explorer:

http://ifotos.pl/zobacz/4JPG_wwaerwh.jpg

bin/debug:

http://ifotos.pl/zobacz/3JPG_wwaereh.jpg

Comment: Maybe you have an x86, x64 issue there? You could check with [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) if there is any Dependency missing.

Comment: Actually I found an answer two days ago.
.net framework 4.5 was a problem. When I've changed to 4.0 it started working.
Thanks anyway. :)